# to remove extra blank space inside square brackets

Tags: javascript, jquery, regex

[1]: http://jsfiddle.net/uZRQt/1/

This is the link which can be used to remove all html tags inside the square brackets but should include the () round brackets inside teh square brackets.

Now can the regex be modified to remove all the html tags , and blank spaces (&nbps) should be removed but the  content inside round bracket should be included :-

for example :-

```
 '<table style="height: 1000px; ; width: 500px;" border="1"> <tbody> <tr> <td>[<span>Assignment name</span>]</td> <td>[<span>&nbsp;Total No of staff-months of(hdhdhdh) the assignment</span>]</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> </tbody> </table>'
```

should give output as

```
 '<table style="height: 1000px; ; width: 500px;" border="1"> <tbody> <tr> <td>[Assignment name]</td> <td>[Total No of staff-months of(hdhdhdh) the assignment]</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> <tr> <td>&nbsp;</td> <td>&nbsp;</td> </tr> </tbody> </table>'
```

Comment: Your expected output includes the `<span>` tags in the first case but your question specifies that HTML tags should be removed.

Comment: Let me also note that [this is not a task for regular expressions](http://www.stackoverflow.com/questions/1732348/regex-match-open-tags-except-xhtml-self-contained-tags/1732454#1732454). Consider parsing the DOM instead.

Answer (score 0):

I changed to single quotes for the main string like in http://jsfiddle.net/uZRQt/1/ and the alert works and returns what you asked. But was that the result you were asking for? I haven't understood completely your question.

Answer (score 0):

> can the regex be modified to remove all the html tags , and blank
>   spaces (&nbps) should be removed but the content inside round bracket
>   should be included :-

Check this one remove All tags and

```
regex:(?<=\[.*) (<[/]?[^>]*?>|&nbsp;)(?=.*\])
```